# Why doesn't setting `random.seed(42)` give me identical results in pytorch?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, random-seed

I am setting random seed for both random and numpy.random at the beginning of my main file:

```
import random
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
random.seed(42)
import torch
```

Nevertheless, when I create a Net() object with randomly initialized parameters, it gives a completely different result every time:

```
net=neuralnet.Net()
print ("initialized params: ", net.fc1.weight)
```

Note that `neuralnet.Net()` is in a different file, and is a class that extends `torch.nn.Module`. it is `torch.nn.Module` that is randomly initializing `net.fc1.weight`, not my own code.

**How is it possible that when I create a Net() object with randomly initialized parameters, it gives a completely different result every time?**

Comment: Please, they wrote a page specifically for this: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)
```

For further information:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7068?

There are some recommendations on how to reproduce the results.

Example:

```
import sys
import random
import datetime as dt

import numpy as np
import torch

torch.manual_seed(42)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)
random.seed(42)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

features = torch.randn(2, 5)

# Print stuff.
fnp = features.view(-1).numpy()

print("Time: {}".format(dt.datetime.now()))
for el in fnp:
    print("{:.20f}".format(el))

print("Python: {}".format(sys.version))
print("Numpy: {}".format(np.__version__))
print("Pytorch: {}".format(torch.__version__))
```